# Routing optional parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I'm working on my first web api and I'm stuck trying to create rules for these urls

```
1) http://mydomain.com/values/4 --> this number can be any, this is just an example
2) http://mydomain.com/values/
3) http://mydomain.com/values/?param1=test1&param2=test2
4) http://mydomain.com/values/?param1=test1
5) http://mydomain.com/values/?param2=test2
```

My current routing rules are

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "Route1",
    routeTemplate: "{controller}/{id}/"
);
routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "Route2",
    routeTemplate: "{controller}/{param1}/{param2}",
    defaults: new { param1 = RouteParameter.Optional, param2 = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

And my methods serving these urls

```
// GET values/
// GET values/?param1=test1&param2=test2
// GET values/?param1=test1
// GET values/?param2=test2
public IEnumerable Get(string param1, string param2)
{
    return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
}

// GET values/5
public string Get(int id)
{
    return "value";
}
```

I have 2 problems

1) `http://mydomain.com/values/` is not resolving

2) `http://mydomain.com/values/?param1=test1` and `http://mydomain.com/values/?param2=test2` are not resolving.

Could you help me to create routes for serving these urls?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "Route1",
    routeTemplate: "{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

Should do what you need.  Query string parameters are already mapped to Action parameters as long as they are named the same, no need to add them in the route.

Comment: Thanks, this works perfect. The only problem is that I would like to keep to separated methods as I stated on my question. Your route works if I have a single method with this signature `public IEnumerable Get(int? id, string param1, string param2)`

Comment: You can have Get(int? id), Get(int? id, string param1) or any combination, the route does not disallow that.

Comment: I would like to have `Get(int? id)` (for url 1 on my list), `Get(string param1, string param2)` (for the rest). Is it possible?

Comment: If you have some extra minutes please answer quesiton I've done on previous comment. Even if you don't know it I'll mark this as resolved as it helped me at least to find 1 way to implement this. Thanks

Comment: You would need to remove the id as optional (remove it completely) from the route to eliminate needing int? id.  However, if you always know the id will be null, whats the harm in Get(int? id, string param1, string param2)

Comment: I have 2 separated scenarios: 1) urls containing `/id` 2) urls not containint `/id` and having an optative querystring -> param1 and param2, one of those, or simply no param. That's why I wanted to have 2 separated method, because they are to separated use cases.

Answer (score 2):

First you don't need the route

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
  name: "Route2",
  routeTemplate: "{controller}/{param1}/{param2}",
  defaults: new { param1 = RouteParameter.Optional, param2 = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

Secondly to resolve `http://mydomain.com/values/` you need to make parameter `id` optional by making it `int?`

```
// GET values/5
public string Get(int? id)
{
  return "value";
}
```

Comment: Sorry @Asif, but that is wrong.  If you do that, then the route {id} would have to be be set to optional. Second, if you only call the url with ?param2=..., you do not hit the overload with two parameters.

Comment: if you don't want id to be optional then how http://mydomain.com/values/  will resolve without id. Second param2 is recognised by the name, for query strings you don't need to define routes.

Comment: Try it and see.  If you don't set {id} to optional, then  mydomain.com/values won't work.

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't work. It doesn't solve any of my problems :(